# How to update slider value by FileInput Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I created an interactive Bokeh dashboard with several sliders. The configuration of all the sliders represent one scenario, which can be exported to a CSV file. Now I would like to be able to reload the scenario, which is stored in a CSV to update the values of the sliders.
Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: failed to validate Slider(id='3566', ...).value: expected a value of type Real, got [16.] of type ndarray
```

I dont understand what is meant with "type Real" and how to adjust it.

The FileInput lines look as follows:

```
 def import_data(attr, old, new):

            decoded = b64decode(new)
            f = io.BytesIO(decoded)
            
            df=pd.read_csv(f, sep=';', engine='python')
            dff = pd.DataFrame(df)
            
            source=ColumnDataSource(data=dff)          
            slider.value=source.data['Column1'] #the column has only 1 row with the value 16
            slider2.value=source.data['Column2']
            slider3.value=source.data['Column3']

            
 file_input.on_change('value', import_data)
```

I have basically tried the same thing without ColumnDataSoure, but it resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The slider value must be set to a number ("Real number ") value not an array. In this case, an index can to be added to the row

```
slider.value=source.data['Column1'][0]
```